# How to Get Child Process IDs Without the jobs Command

Tags: shell

Okay, so I'm working with a shell script that needs to be as portable as possible, and I want to make sure I can cleanly tidy up any child-processes using a `trap` command.

Now, on more recent platforms the `jobs -p` command can be used to get a list of child process ids, suitable for throwing straight into a `kill` command to tidy things up without any fuss.

However, some environments don't have this. To work around this I'm using a variable into which I throw process IDs, but it's messy, and a typo could result in some or all child processes not being killed when they should be.

So, in the absence of the `jobs` command, what alternatives are there? Or put another way, what is the most compatible method to kill all child-processes of a script?

To give you an idea of potential limitations; the most basic system I need to work with has no `pgrep`, and only a basic version of `ps` only supporting the `-w` flag. It does have access to special files under `/proc/$$/` but I'm not sure what to do with those (do any of them even list child processes?). This has been a big part of the difficulty, as many similar questions list solutions using tools I don't have access to, I just love compatibility issues =)

Comment: My answer was wrong so I removed it. Sorry for that.

Comment: good explanation, but do  you mean backgrounded processes that are detached as children, or a true 'tree' of processes, descending from a single parent? Also, if you want ultra compatibility, old line uxixen don't have the `/proc` tree (at least the old versions I worked with). Finally, not sure what your common demoninator `/proc/$$` looks like. Is that just one file, 1 sub dir, are there other entities directly below `/proc`. What does `find /proc -print | wc -l` indicate? Good luck.

Comment: Unless you start processes in the background, the shell will wait for them to finish before continuing. And if processes are started in background, it is normally because you want them to run independently from the script. Just going on a killing rampage before courtains makes no sense.

Comment: agree with @vonbrand, unless you can further explain your requirement. Good luck.

Comment: `jobs -p` is part of the POSIX standard. If you have a different definition of "portable" in mind, you'll have to share it. What environment are you using that doesn't support `jobs -p`?

Comment: I need to be able to work with embedded Linux on devices such as NAS systems. The device I've been testing with as a lowest common denominator is a Synology NAS, which uses an `ash` shell identifying itself as `BusyBox v1.16.1`. So far it's been a nightmare, but unfortunately it's what I'm being paid to do! It doesn't appear to have a `jobs` command at all, but does have `/proc/$$/status` if that helps any. @cnicutar, why was your answer wrong?

Comment: @Haravikk Because you have multiple process groups.

Comment: @cnicutar so `kill 0` wouldn't work even if all my child-processes also had that command in their own `trap`?

Answer (score 0):

```
You can get the child pid using `!`

$!
```

Comment: This is essentially what I'm doing already, like: `jobs="$jobs $!"`, but this requires keeping the variable maintained and accurate, which isn't really an ideal way to do things.